# Level of illiteracy, ______ of innumeracy?

Tags: word-choice, writing-style

What noun would one use in the titular phrase?  To my mind, level sounds absolutely correct for the former, but very out of place in the latter.  Instead, I think degree fits better for innumeracy. I generally trust my sentiments in these sorts of things, but I was wondering if english.se would agree or disagree?

Comment: Searching google with quotes around each phrase turns up about 5,600 hits for ["level of innumeracy"](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&q="level+of+innumeracy"), compared to about 1,600 for ["degree of innumeracy"](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&q="degree+of+innumeracy"). Both sound valid to me, but *level* appears to be more common.

Comment: "Quantity of innumeracy" of course.

Answer (score 4):

*Degree of illiteracy*, *degree of innumeracy*, *level of illiteracy* and *level of innumeracy* may all be used.

Comment: I don't mean to be snarky, but that really wasn't my question. I know both phrasings *can* be used, but I was interested in whether one rings more true than the other.    If you detect no difference, of feel the question is too based on opinion for se, say so and I'll be very appreciative for the input.